# In CoreGraphics drawing how can I keep the point of overlap from being darker than the rest of the line?

Tags: iphone, drawing, core-graphics, paint, quartz-2d

My app uses core graphics for custom finger paint drawing. I allow the user to change the alpha of the line and a new line is continuously drawn on touches moved. When I make the alpha lower than 1.0 the point of overlap is darker than the rest of the line. I know why this occurs but how can I stop this?

Comment: Can you please post some code showing how you are drawing the line? I just need to know the method so that i can suggest you something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want a single stroke not to darken itself, but still to darken previous strokes (that's how most painting apps work).

For this to work, you need two views/buffers, one for the 'current background' and one for the current stroke. Merge the latter with the background when the finger is released.

You always draw with alpha 1 in the current stroke buffer, but you display and merge  it with a lower alpha.

Comment: Yes, that's I want. I just created two views for current stroke and old strokes. It works fine except when I call the function to merge the two views the alpha stays 1.0. Is there a way to change the alpha of a UIImage?

Comment: Obviously you have to apply the alpha to the current stroke view when merging it with the old strokes.

Comment: I obviously knew that but I was asking how to change the alpha of a uiimage BUT I figured it out and you have the correct answer, good job!

Comment: can  you explain me the logic.. I am not getting how to proceed.. here is my post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407546/how-do-i-draw-lines-with-alpha-1-in-quartz-2d/9407828#9407828

Comment: @Aspyn check my answer..  A better answer without any need to create 2 views.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407546/how-do-i-draw-lines-with-alpha-1-in-quartz-2d/9477238#9477238