# How do I draw lines with alpha < 1 in quartz 2d

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, quartz-graphics

No doubt this might be a duplicate question but I am not able to get proper solution from any post here. So I am posting this as new post with a hope that I get some solution.

I my drawing app I want to give a feature of opacity for lines to be drawn. 
But when I assign alpha to color, I am getting overlapped points in between the line.

Some where I found that drawing in two views solves this issue, but I was not able to understand the logic behind that.

[image]

I am using normal quartz 2d code to draw line on touch events.

Comment: I've read your question but I'm not sure as to the meaning of 'overlapped points in between the line'.

Comment: @psoft see in the image, while drawing line I can see circles..They are overlapped points.. I dont want them, I want transparent lines..

Comment: oh ok... see my answer below in a few minutes.

Comment: great.. Hope it solve my issue..

Comment: CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hie..

This is my final solution..
I am now drawing lines on drawRect event and drawing the entire line at a time as a path.. 
This creates opacity to retain and now no line caps drawn in between..

No doubt this is the trick that is working since  I am drawing on every touch and this works..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
for (int j=0; j<[pathArray count]; j++) 
{
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSMutableDictionary *tmp=[pathArray objectAtIndex:j];
    NSMutableArray *currentPath=[tmp objectForKey:@"path"];
    for (int i=0; i<[currentPath count]; i++) 
    {
        CGPoint mid1 = [[self midPoint:[currentPath objectAtIndex:i+1]  :[currentPath objectAtIndex:i]] CGPointValue]; 
        CGPoint mid2 = [[self midPoint:[currentPath objectAtIndex:i+2] :[currentPath objectAtIndex:i+1]] CGPointValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, [[currentPath objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue].x, [[currentPath objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue].y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
        CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-2, -2), 3);
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, [[tmp objectForKey: @"opacity"] floatValue]);    
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[[tmp objectForKey: @"Color"] CGColor]);               
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, [[tmp objectForKey: @"width"] floatValue]);              
        i+=2;
    }   
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
}
```

Comment: But this slows down after some touches

Comment: Also draws the entire rect every time which is very slow

Comment: @CrazyCreator what is the "pathArray" in your code ? i want to do like this. can you help me out on this ?

Comment: @crazycreatror can you show me the 1) touchesBegan 2) touchesMoved & 3) touchesEnded method ?

Comment: In touches methods, points are added to path array @Coder.
You can find me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family, during indian Day time

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of [In CoreGraphics drawing how can I keep the point of overlap from being darker than the rest of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328030/in-coregraphics-drawing-how-can-i-keep-the-point-of-overlap-from-being-darker-th/7329573#comment11890071_7329573)

The trick is to have the brush stroke in its own buffer, where you can clip the alpha properly before blending the whole thing with the background.

Here's one way to do that: Create 2 views, one for the background, another one for the lines. Draw the lines in the top view with an alpha of 1! Then set the alpha of this whole foreground view to 0.5 (or whatever value you want to use).

```
[topView setAlpha:0.5];
```

That will prevent a semi-transparent brush stroke from intensifying itself. But what about 2 different brush strokes that cross each other (like in your example). Do you want that intersection to be more intense? If so, then you need to create a new view for every brush stroke. To prevent memory overflow for having too many views, you then need to blend the previous top view(s) with the background.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're drawing a circle at every point of a series of touch events. Instead, you can build a [**Path**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101) with `CoreGraphics/Quartz2D`, set the line width to be whatever thickness, and then stroke that path as needed to keep the UI looking nice. I've not done this in a while, but I think most of what you need will be in `CoreGraphics/CGContext.h` and `~/CGPath.h, etc.` See my answer to another CoreGraphics problem [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405725/using-cgcontext-to-draw-line/9405900#9405900).

The one unknown in my mind right now is whether you can stroke a CGMutablePathRef to a context before you 'close' it using `CGPathCloseSubpath()`. You'll have to experiment. At any rate, as you receive mouse events, you will build a path up with the new points and render it a little at a time. Let me know if you need clarification.

P.S. as for `opacity`, you will *set* it when you create the `CGColorRef` for your context... many of the calls in `CoreGraphics/CGColor.h` have an alpha parameter.

Comment: I am not drawing circles.. They are line caps being drawn when I draw paths..  I tried setting alpha parameter but its giving this result :(

Comment: You know, the more I think about this, the more I think that you will just have to push a context for each gesture, render the path opaque, but then apply the context using your desired alpha at the end of the gesture, or, I suppose, after every touch event. That or reinvent CGContext's mitering/joining logic and draw your own 'metapath', meaning the boundary around your path, then fill the meta path. But a bunch of off-screen contexts should do fine. What do you think?

Comment: Or I imagine that it wouldn't be too terrible for the user to see his lines render as opaque *during* his gesture and then transition to translucent after he stops. Food for thought. But I think this is your solution.

Comment: ya that is one solution.. but not good.. :( can say not acceptable

Comment: I am not getting ur previous comment.. Pushing context each time?? If I have understood to the point then dont u think it will make application heavy??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH210-TPXREF101

Comment: This makes drawing too slow.. and yet its not solving problem :(

Comment: The only way to avoid the line caps (I think) is to draw opaque lines, but you can't draw them onto your context. So you have to draw them somewhere else and then render that thing onto your context in a non-opaque fashion. I think that's what the transparency layers are for.

Comment: Ok, I think that's all the help I can lend tonight. Good luck!

Comment: I understand your point.. But not getting the way to solve this problem... Drawing opaque line and then making transparent is not the way other paint app doing.. I dont know.. It should be instantaneous..

Comment: okay.. Thanks.. I am too going for lunch.. If u ever get some solution.. Please post it here.. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Touch Event

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:drawView];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawView.frame.size);

    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawView.frame.size.width, drawView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawView.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawView.frame.size.width, drawView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: This wont help me.. Since alpha value is 1.00.. Try with alpha  < 1 and u will get why that is challenging..

Comment: This is the thing I already implemented.. I want that some editing which is needed to get my things done..

Comment: Try with alpha < 1 and u will get why that is challenging.